# Are there any textbooks with very thoughtful quantum mechanics problems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

David Morin's book on classical mechanics is one of my favourite textbooks because of the amount of care that went into constructing the amazing end-of-chapter problems. I haven't found anything comparable in QM yet (where I am forced to think very critically about the problems, and the results are fun and elegant). I was wondering if anyone had some recommendations?

Comment: This might be only my opinion but it'd be better if you clarify as to "critically" in what sense. Critically about mathematical formalism, critically about conceptual questions, critically about applications of the basic principles? Also, and this is secondary, if you can provide some examples of other books you went through and how do you distinguish Morin from them, this can help one understand what exactly you're looking for.